# I have a single array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:
[

```
0] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_fname] => Aristo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [u_fname] => Anil
        )
```

But, I want my array in this form:

```
array(array[0]=>
   array([uid]=>0,['u_name']=>Aristo)),
   array([1]=>[uid]=>1,['u_name']=>Anil)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code. Have you searched for answers to your question yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

//this is your array in question
$single = array(
    array(
        'u_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'u_fname' => Aristo
    ),
    array(
        'u_id' => 6
    ),
    array(
        'u_fname' => Anil
    )
);

print_r($single);

$multi = array_map(function($item) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($item, function($value, $index) use (&$return) {
        $return[$index] = $value; //flatten array, but keeping index
    });
    return $return;
}, array_chunk($single, 2)); //split array into sections containing two elements

print_r($multi);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/d8ddd15aaa3ae2):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_fname] => Aristo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [u_fname] => Anil
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 1
            [u_fname] => Aristo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 6
            [u_fname] => Anil
        )

)
```